# Craft 3.x Menu : Entry URLs are set by the entry

Tags: entry, url, custom

I can't change the URL? How can I use a custom URL?
Here is the link to the image:
https://ibb.co/bz9BYnL

Comment: Update*
I noticed that when I updated an editable url and saved, the url field went blank, then the message onhover over that field came up "Entry URLs are set by the entry". This seems like a bug in the software? Editing and saving a URL should not break the navigation item.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following... is this in the context of a plugin? Can you edit the question and maybe add some screenshots of what you're seeing and what you're trying to do?

Comment: Another piece to the puzzle. If I look at the DB in PHPmyAdmin, I notice the Entry ID is NULL. Entry ID appears to be the URL.

Comment: bump.
Never mind. I ended up destroying the menu an recreating.
Another reason I dislike craft. Not much help in the community I guess.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel like that, the Craft community is generally very helpful. Your question is at best vague I'm afraid, I still don't understand what you're asking even after Brad's request for clarification. If you take time to explain your problem carefully and in detail, you may receive a better response.

Comment: Needs clarification. That image is no longer available.  You can just drag or paste screenshots into your question.  If your question is less than one full line, then the  odds are high that you could do more work explaining what you'd like others to help you with.